# VB.Net Copy a list to store original values to be used later

Tags: vb.net, list, collections

I have a WPF form that takes a list of objects that have locations and sizes and plots them on the canvas. I'm currently trying to implement an undo button that will throw out all the changes that have been made to the positions of the objects and revert back to the original collection that was retrieved when the form loaded.

As it stands now I go out to the database on the load of the form and get all the objects that will need to be displayed then assign the list that is returned to two seperate collections. The problem that comes up is that the two collections are actually pointers to the original collection and whenever one is changed the changes are reflected in the second collection.

Is it possible to copy a list of objects so that changes made to one collection won't affect the secondary collection?

So far I've tried simply using the assignment operator, passing the source collection into a function `byval` and scrolling through each element of the list manually adding it to the second collection and using linq to get all the objects from the original list and pushing the results to a separate temporary list and assigning the second collection to the temporary list.

I feel like I'm overcomplicating the issue but almost all the places I've come across while googling say that this behavior is by design, which I understand but it seems like this would be a fairly common idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a function I have used before to make "Deep" copies of objects:

```
Public Function DeepCopy(ByVal ObjectToCopy As Object) As Object

    Using mem as New MemoryStream

        Dim bf As New BinaryFormatter
        bf.Serialize(mem, ObjectToCopy)

        mem.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin)

        Return bf.Deserialize(mem)

    End Using

End Function
```

This is kind of a low level approach compared to some of the other answers, but allows you to deep copy any object.  I've used it successfully in a situation similar to yours where I needed a deep copy of an array.

Comment: While trying to implement this function I noticed that for it to work as generically as possible, all the custom classes i make would have to be marked as `serializable` in the times that you've used this function have you seen any reason that marking a class `serializable` would be ill advised?

Comment: I don't recall using it on a custom class, so I can't comment on that specifically.  However, I don't think you will run into any issues provided the class is marked as serializable.

Comment: After adding `<Serializable()>` to all my affected class definitions this function worked like a charm, and much faster than the third party control that I found to do roughly the same job.

Answer (score 1):

Simply assign all items of the listA to listB using this code

```
For Each elm In ListA
   ListB.Add(elm) 
Next
```

Comment: From my testing I was seeing that `ListB` would contain references to the items in `ListA` so any changes to `ListA` would be reflected in `ListB`. The Deep copy from Casey Wilkins fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

There was another answer that was since deleted that said to use `var copy = list.ToList();` to get a copy of the list.  This will work with the following caveat:  Both lists will still reference the same objects, so any changes to those objects will reflect in both lists.  As long as you're only changing the order of the objects in the list, this solution is perfectly viable.

Comment: The main issue is that certain values are being changed though(position in this case) so this approach didn't work out.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to create a new list and add copies of the items in list1 to it.  You could do this using object initialization, e.g.

```
Dim list2 = (From item in list1
             Select New ItemType With {.Property1 = item.Property1, .Property2 = item.Property2}.ToList()
```

An alternative would be to add a Copy constructor to ItemType

```
Public Sub New(item as ItemType)
    Me.Property1 = item.Property1
    Me.Property2 = item.Property2
End Sub
```

And your list copy could be simplified to

```
Dim list2 = (From item in list1
             Select New ItemType(item)}.ToList()
```

Just beware that if any of the properties of your ItemType are references, you would need to make copies of these objects also.  (This is known as a [Deep Copy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_copy#Deep_copy))

Comment: I tried something like this but the object that I would be copying is rather large and has additional objects as data members so it became counterproductive from a speed point of view fairly quickly(recursive function calls and 100+ instances of starter objects sort of thing). Also, thank you for that link, I was familiar with the principles it talked about but had never heard the names for them and its always good to be able to use the correct terms for things.