# Reference of parent collection affecting the assigned collection

Tags: .net, vb.net, multithreading, winforms

**Task:**
I have a requirement(User able to save continuously one after the other without waiting) so i choose multi-threading and i was about to complete that with the Queue concept. But i have stuck up in one scenario.

**Task regarding code:**
There was many collections and objects in the application for which i have created a single Queue class and created a separate collections and objects in that and all those were assigned to the queue class objects. Whenever the user saves the changes all those collections and objects are filled and assigned to the queue collections and objects and added in the queue, So the background worker takes the collections and objects and do the process. This is done to make sure that the values saved are for the correct since there is continuous save.

**Scenario:**
The application has a grid in which the user selects a row and using a Unique Id from it the values are loaded in the collection and bind to the form. So the user will update the values and click on save. Then he clicks on the next row and once the values are loaded he makes the changes again and save.This is where the problems arise.

Since i have assigned all the previous collection to the queue collection, when the user make the changes and clicks on save and he goes for the next row and clicks on that, the collection present already in the application is getting reset(Since the collection is reset for every row selection to load the selected value) and the new values are loaded. This makes the changes reflecting the collection which i have in the queue also. So the save functionality is getting affected in between.

Now i need is the, Collection which i have in the queue should not get affected even when the collection present already gets reset.

How can i achieve?

//Code:

**MainForm:**

Public Class Form1

```
''Queue collection of a class
'Dim oQueueCollection As New Queue(Of MyItem)
''Backgroundworker instance
'Dim bw As BackgroundWorker = New BackgroundWorker()


'Backgroundworker instance
Dim m_oBackgroundWorker As BackgroundWorker = Nothing

'Queue collection of a class
Dim m_cQueueCollection As New Queue(Of BackgroundworkerController)

Dim m_cBackgroundworkerController As New BackgroundworkerController


Private Property Item As New Item

''' <summary>
''' Get or set the Item Pricing collection.
''' </summary>
''' <value></value>
''' <returns></returns>
''' <remarks></remarks>
Public Property ItemPricingCollection() As Collection(Of ItemPricing) = New Collection(Of ItemPricing)


Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    'Initialize the backgroud worker
    m_oBackgroundWorker = New BackgroundWorker()

    'Call the completed method once the thread completes it work
    m_oBackgroundWorker.WorkerReportsProgress = True


    'Create thread and continue with the process
    AddHandler m_oBackgroundWorker.DoWork, AddressOf bw_DoWork

    'Method called after the thread work completes
    AddHandler m_oBackgroundWorker.RunWorkerCompleted, AddressOf bw_RunWorkerCompleted

End Sub

Private Sub SaveItem()
    'Shows the item that starts the save.
    MsgBox(m_cQueueCollection.First().Item.ItemNo)

    'Makes the thread to sleep for the delay(In between we can make the next save)--- Testing purpose only
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(13000)
End Sub

Private Sub bw_DoWork(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DoWorkEventArgs)

    'Calls the save method
    SaveItem()

    'Shows the saved/Completed item's No
    'This Id will be assinged to all the places in which the application needs the current itemno(PK).
    e.Result = m_cQueueCollection.First().Item.ItemNo & " is Completed"

    'Removes the Completed item in queue
    m_cQueueCollection.Dequeue()
End Sub

Private Sub bw_RunWorkerCompleted(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs)
    'shows the result
    MsgBox(e.Result)

    'Check the collection and disable the timer in order not to run un necessarily
    If (m_cQueueCollection.Count = 0) Then
        Timer1.Enabled = False
        Timer1.Stop()
    End If
End Sub


Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    'ThreadPoolTest()

    'Sets the class to a property
    'this is done in order to have multiple class/collections inside the queue for processing
    m_cBackgroundworkerController.Item = Me.Item
    m_cBackgroundworkerController.ItemPricingCollection = Me.ItemPricingCollection

    'I have trided
    'm_cBackgroundworkerController.Item = DirectCast(Me.Item.clone(), Item)


    'Adds the collection to the queue
    m_cQueueCollection.Enqueue(m_cBackgroundworkerController)

    'enables the timer
    Timer1.Enabled = True

End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Me.Item = Nothing
    Me.ItemPricingCollection.Clear()
End Sub

'Checks the collection and background worker and start the thread process for every 1 second.
'If the thread is running it just exits.

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    If (m_cQueueCollection.Count > 0 AndAlso Not m_oBackgroundWorker.IsBusy) Then
        m_oBackgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync()
    End If
End Sub

End Class
```

//BackgroundWorkerClass:

```
Public Class BackgroundworkerController

Implements IDisposable



Private Shared s_bDisposed As Boolean
''' <summary>
''' Get or set the item.
''' </summary>
''' <value></value>
''' <returns></returns>
''' <remarks></remarks>  
Public Property Item() As Item = New Item



''' <summary>
''' Get or set the Item Pricing collection.
''' </summary>
''' <value></value>
''' <returns></returns>
''' <remarks></remarks>
Public Property ItemPricingCollection() As Collection(Of ItemPricing) = New Collection(Of ItemPricing)

End class
```

//One of the class:

```
<Serializable()> _
Public Class Item
    Implements IDisposable

    Private m_sItemNo As String = ""
   Private sEnvironmentCode sItemNo As String = ""
    Private m_bIsChanged As Boolean
    Private m_bIsInDatabase As Boolean



'jw10 end new collections added

''' <summary>
''' Get or set the Item Number.
''' </summary>
''' <value></value>
''' <returns></returns>
''' <remarks></remarks>
Public Property ItemNo() As String

    Get
        Return Me.m_sItemNo
    End Get

    Set(ByVal value As String)
        If Not Me.IsLoading Then Me.IsChanged = True
        Me.m_sItemNo = value
    End Set

End Property

''' <summary>
''' Get or set the environment code.
''' </summary>
''' <value></value>
''' <returns></returns>
''' <remarks></remarks>
Public Property EnvironmentCode() As String

    Get
        Return Me.m_sEnvironmentCode
    End Get

    Set(ByVal value As String)
        If Me.m_sEnvironmentCode <> value Then Me.m_bIsChanged = True
        Me.m_sEnvironmentCode = value
    End Set

End Property



''' <summary>
''' Get or set the changed flag.
''' </summary>
''' <value></value>
''' <returns></returns>
''' <remarks></remarks>
Public Property IsChanged() As Boolean

    Get
        Return Me.m_bIsChanged
    End Get

    Set(ByVal Value As Boolean)
        Me.m_bIsChanged = Value
    End Set

End Property



''' <summary>
''' Get or set the is in database flag.
''' </summary>
''' <value></value>
''' <returns></returns>
''' <remarks></remarks>
Public Property IsInDatabase() As Boolean

    Get
        Return Me.m_bIsInDatabase
    End Get

    Set(ByVal Value As Boolean)
        Me.m_bIsInDatabase = Value
    End Set

End Property

Public Overloads Sub Dispose() Implements IDisposable.Dispose

    'Check to see if dispose has already been called
    If Not s_bDisposed Then

        'Call the dispose method 
        Me.Dispose(True)

        'Tell the garbage collector that the object doesn't require cleanup 
        GC.SuppressFinalize(Me)

    End If

End Sub

Protected Overridable Overloads Sub Dispose(ByVal disposing As Boolean)

    'Flag class as disposed 
    s_bDisposed = True

End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have face the same problem. I got the idea from below link.

[VB.Net Copy a list to store original values to be used later](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10745026/vb-net-copy-a-list-to-store-original-values-to-be-used-later)

### Try the below code

```
'Sets the class to a property
'this is done in order to have multiple class/collections inside the queue for processing
m_cBackgroundworkerController.Item = CType(DeepCopy(Me.Item), Item)
m_cBackgroundworkerController.ItemPricingCollection = CType(DeepCopy(Me.ItemPricingCollection), Collection(Of ItemPricing))


'Adds the collection to the queue
m_cQueueCollection.Enqueue(m_cBackgroundworkerController)

'enables the timer
Timer1.Enabled = True




Public Function DeepCopy(ByVal ObjectToCopy As Object) As Object

    Using mem as New MemoryStream

        Dim bf As New BinaryFormatter
        bf.Serialize(mem, ObjectToCopy)

        mem.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin)

        Return bf.Deserialize(mem)

    End Using

End Function
```

Comment: The code was working fine. But, since i have many collections i have to do this for every one. Is thr any simpler way? for the reference type.???

Answer (score 0):

First, your "Item" class should implement the "System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged" interface.  This is basically so changes made to the class will be reflected in your grid without having to "reset" the collection/grid.

Second, Only send what needs to be saved to your queue, not ALL records.

Third, when the save is done, update (if need be) the "Item" class that was saved (one property at a time), do not replace the item in the collection or anything like that.

This should help you get pointed down the right path.  When you run into new problems, create a new question.

Comment: Can u post any simple code to achieve what u explained? I'm not much clear.