# Return any Type in C#

Tags: c#, .net, dynamic, ado.net

I have a scenario where i have to return different type of objects according to a condition.

For that i have used `dynamic` return type in c# 4.0.

But i couldn't achieve that.

```
public dynamic ValidateUser(string UserName, string Password)
{
    string Result = string.Empty;

    Employees clsEmployee = new Employees();
    Customer clsCustomer = new Customer();

    sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(Connection());
    command = new SqlCommand("dbo.usp_ValidateUser", sqlConnection);
    command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    command.Parameters.Add("@Username", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = UserName;
    command.Parameters.Add("@Password", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Password;
    sqlConnection.Open();

    SqlParameter newSqlParam = new SqlParameter();
    newSqlParam.ParameterName = "@Result";
    newSqlParam.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.NVarChar;
    newSqlParam.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
    newSqlParam.Size = 50;
    command.Parameters.Add(newSqlParam);

    SqlDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader();
    Result = command.Parameters["@Result"].Value.ToString();

    if (Result == "Employee")
    {
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            clsEmployee.EmployeeId = (int)dr["EmployeeId"];
            clsEmployee.EmployeeName = (string)dr["EmployeeName"];
            clsEmployee.DepartmentName = (string)dr["DepartmentName"];
            clsEmployee.RoleName = (string)dr["RoleName"];
        }    
        return clsEmployee;
    }
    else if (Result == "Customer")
    {
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            clsCustomer.CustomerId = (int)dr["CustomerId"];
            clsCustomer.CustomerName = (string)dr["CustomerName"];
            clsCustomer.CustomerEmail = (string)dr["CustomerEmail"];
            clsCustomer.CustomerMobile = (string)dr["CustomerMobile"];
        }
        return clsCustomer;
    }


    //How to return???
}
```

When i try to return inside the condition it throws me

> Not all code path return value' error.

Any solutions?

Comment: Why don't you either split authentication into a separate class from population, or at least return `IPerson`? `dynamic` is almost never the correct solution.

Comment: Instead of having the last `else` statement, just `return Result;`

Comment: I strongly suspect this isn't your actual code, otherwise you wouldn't have got that error message. I suspect your final `else` is actually an `else if` or something like that.

Comment: As Tim suggest, I strongly suggest to use Interface or some parent class, Maybe a User Type class that later got inherited as customer or Employee, and you always return User Class object.

Comment: And do you *really* want to return just a string if the result is unexpected? That seems highly odd to me. Like Tim, I question the design here.

Comment: Sorry all, it seems i have written the correct code and missed the last else part in the real code. It works now.

Comment: Dynamic doesn't buy you much over object here - might as well return object IMO

Comment: This is a design flaw. I would recommend rethinking it entirely.

Comment: @JonSkeet: Can you please look into this ques of mine and i need a clear suggestion with a sample.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19054454/reference-of-parent-collection-affecting-the-assigned-collection

Comment: @SanthoshKumar: That's an unrelated question. Please don't abuse the comment system to try to attract attention to different questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove the `else` part:

```
else if (Result == "Customer")
{
    while (dr.Read())
    {
        clsCustomer.CustomerId = (int)dr["CustomerId"];
        clsCustomer.CustomerName = (string)dr["CustomerName"];
        clsCustomer.CustomerEmail = (string)dr["CustomerEmail"];
        clsCustomer.CustomerMobile = (string)dr["CustomerMobile"];
    }
    return clsCustomer;
}
return Result;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
switch (Result)
{
    case "Employee":
    {
        ...
        return ...
    }
    case "Customer":
    {
        ...
        return ....
    }
    default:
        return Result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Santhosh,

This is not a proper way to handle different types. You could consider the implementation of an interface to achieve this. This make more readability and much more extensible. I believe that you are working on a support code, so that you may  have limitation for achieving the new implementation.

I think you could change like this

```
public object ValidateUser(string UserName, string Password)
{
    object retVal= null;
    string Result = String.Empty;

    Employees clsEmployee = new Employees();
    Customer clsCustomer = new Customer();

    // get the data
    Result = command.Parameters["@Result"].Value.ToString();

    if (Result == "Employee")
    {
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            clsEmployee.EmployeeId = (int)dr["EmployeeId"];
            clsEmployee.EmployeeName = (string)dr["EmployeeName"];
            clsEmployee.DepartmentName = (string)dr["DepartmentName"];
            clsEmployee.RoleName = (string)dr["RoleName"];
        }

        retVal=clsEmployee;
    }
   if (Result == "Customer")
    {
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            clsCustomer.CustomerId = (int)dr["CustomerId"];
            clsCustomer.CustomerName = (string)dr["CustomerName"];
            clsCustomer.CustomerEmail = (string)dr["CustomerEmail"];
            clsCustomer.CustomerMobile = (string)dr["CustomerMobile"];
        }

        retVal=clsCustomer;
    }
     retVal=Result;
     return retVal;
    }
```

I think this will eliminates the current problem.